# Tax calculation in vba, run type error '13' type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim Salary As Double
Dim Income As Double
Dim Tax As Double
Dim SalaryAfterTax As Double
Dim strOutput As String

Salary = InputBox("Please indicate your salary", "Salary Calculation")

Income = CDbl(Salary)

Select Case Income
Case Is >= 151000
     Tax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (150000 - 37400) * 0.5 + (Salary - 150000) * 0.5

Case Is >= 37401
     Tax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (Salary - 37400) * 0.4

Case Is >= 2441
     Tax = 2440 * 0.1 + (Salary - 2440) * 0.2

Case Else
     Tax = 2440 * 0.1

End Select

SalaryAfterTax = Income - Tax

strOutput = "Your salary after tax is" & SalaryAfterTax

MsgBox strOutput, "Final Salary"

End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly is your error occurring?

Comment: Just an FYI, you are getting downvoted by the community because you did not do any explanation into the problem.  There should have been some commentary on which line is throwing the error and such.  As it was it was an easy to reproduce error in that there were no cells that were being referenced, so I answered.  Next time put more than just  the code in the question.

Comment: Thank you Scott, i will make sure to explain about my problem next time. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
MsgBox strOutput, "Final Salary"
```

To:

```
MsgBox strOutput, vbOKOnly, "Final Salary"
```

Or:

```
MsgBox Prompt:=strOutput, Title:="Final Salary"
```

You are trying to put a string in where a button type is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks alot Scott.. really appreciate your help :)